# Multiple attributes Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, attributes, configurable-product, magento-2.1

I have 2 attributes for product variations I want to use (size, width). In Magento 1 I was able to quickly add each associated product one-by-one with quick product creation. But in Magento 2 it seems that I am forced to create all combinations of these 2 attributes when creating variations? This is unnecessary if lets say I have 10 sizes of one width, but only 1 of the other width. In this process I end up with a bunch of extra products that don't even exist.
Is there something I'm missing here or an alternative approach rather than manually creating each simple product?

Thanks